# Setting a variable with square bracket in cshell (UNIX)

Tags: unix, csh, tcsh

```csh
set capportName = bl_l#ob0#cb
set portName = `echo "${capportName}" | sed -e "s:#ob:\[:g" -e "s:#cb:\]:g" `
echo "$portName"
```

OUTPUT:

```
set: No match.
```

I want the `portName` to have `#ob` replaced with open square bracket '[' and `#cb` to be replaced with closed square bracket ']' so that later I can do the following operation:

```csh
fgrep -A2 "print_resistance ${portName}" log
```

where `portName` variable should have the right name which is brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason to not simply use the literal square brackets?

```csh
set portName = "bl_l[0]"
echo "$portName"
```

Quoting in `csh` is really pesky, to the point where most people simply [give up and switch to a different shell](https://www.mars.org/home/rob/docs/csh-whynot.html).  For reference, the code will look pretty similar in Bourne shell;

```sh
portName="bl_l[0]"  # no "set", no spaces around equals signs
echo "$portName"
```